# java restful service client accepting list of response

Tags: java, rest

I am trying to write a java client for restful resource. The response for my request is a list of objects. I have the following code for the request. BUt i get some unmarshall exception. Could anyone let me know how to solve this ?

```
 GenericType<List<Response>> genType = new GenericType<List<Response>>() {};
 GenericType<List<Response>> response = (GenericType<List<Response>>)resource.path(paramPath).accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).get(genType);
```

my resource has the following code

```
@GET
@Path("/app/{Id}")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public List<Response> getAllKeyValuesByAppId(@PathParam("Id") Long Id){
    ...
    ...
}
```

Comment: what is the `Response` class?

Comment: can you give the stack trace for the exception? And I assume you're using Jersey as your REST framework and Jackson for marshalling/unmarshalling?

Comment: Response class is my user defined class

Answer (score 0):

Can you test you REST method without unmarshaling?
Are you sure that the message body contains exactly what you expect?